# Repeatedly assigning people to subgroups so everyone knows each other

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

Say a teacher divides his students into subgroups once every class. The profile of subgroup sizes is the same everyday (e.g. with 28 students it might be always 8 groups of 3 and 1 group of 4). How can the teacher specify the subgroup assignments for a classes so that in the shortest number of classes, everyone has been in a subgroup with everyone else? Exhaustive search seems intractable, so what would be good optimization approach?

Edit: To clarify, I'm assuming the subgroup structure is given and fixed. The optimization is just the assignment of students to groups across the days.

Comment: I found that this is known as the [Social Golfer's Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69325/social-golfer-problem-quintets) and is solved only for small set of low-number settings.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest number of classes is 1, with a single subgroup that contains all the students.

The second shortest number of classes is 3, which is achieved with one small subgroup and a large one.  For example, ABCDEFG/HI, ABCDEHI/FG, ABCFGHI/DE.

The proof that 2 classes is impossible: let X, Y be the two largest subgroups from the first day.  Each member of X must meet each member of Y on the second day, but to do this would create a subgroup larger than either X or Y.

Comment: My understanding of the question is different -- I understood is as having the subgroup structure given and fixed; and us trying to find the minimum number of classes with such structure (and also the actual assignments of students into the groups in each class).

Comment: Thanks [Peter](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/77812/peter-kosinar), I've clarified above.