# How can I find the smallest set of groups of $n$ elements such that every element is in the same group as every other at least once?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Background: I'm working on [a King of the Hill challenge](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1856/3808) for [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com), and I've run into a problem with how I'm creating the individual matchups (groups of 4 entries).

Currently, I'm simply generating all combinations of 4 elements (in the combinatoric sense) of entries, but that gets *really* big *really* quickly:

$$x \choose 4$$

[image: graph]

<sup>(from [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+of+x+choose+4+for+x+from+0+to+70))</sup>

Therefore, my question is: **How can I choose subsets (of length $n$) of a set such that each element of that set appears in the same subset as every other element at least once, while maintaining a minimal amount of subsets?**

I can figure this out for $n = 2$, since the solution is quite intuitive: simply combine the first element with every other element, combine the second element with every other element that comes after it, etc. For a set of length $L$, this yields:

$$\sum_{x=1}^{L-1}(L - x)$$

[image: graph 2]

<sup>(from [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+of+sum+y-x%2C+x%3D1+to+y-1+for+y+from+0+to+70))</sup>

which is much smaller and more manageable.

However, I still have not been able to figure out: **How can I generalize this to any $n$?**

Comment: The short answer is likely to be that there is no way to avoid the numbers being very large. Big sets have lots of small subsets. Your issue is presumably going to be more algorithm specific: given that doing it all at once is too resource intensive, how to break things up into manageable pieces in the most efficient way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the sum you figured out for n = 2 is exactly the same as L-choose-2. There could be a smaller number for n > 2, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple formula for the general case.

What you are asking about are called [block covering designs](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/designs/covering_design.html).  Specifically, a $(v,k,t)$-design is a collection of $k$-element subsets ("blocks") of (say) $\{1,2,\ldots,v\}$ such that any $t$-element subset is contained in at least one block.  Your "universe" has size $n$, but the convention in this area is to use $v$ for the total number of points/individuals.

Things are fairly well understood for $t=2$, which seems to be your "individual matchups".  A quick reference/database for known block covering designs is the (now migrated) [La Jolla Covering Repository](https://www.dmgordon.org/cover/).

For example, with ten players (in groups of four), we can achieve all $45$ pairings using only nine blocks, much fewer than the easily computed but excessive $\binom{10}{4}=210$ collection of all possible foursomes.

A good starting point for constructing these designs for specific $(v,k,t)$ is Gordan et al [New Constructions for Covering Designs (1995)](https://www.dmgordon.org/papers/cover.pdf).  In many cases designs are known but not whether they achieve the minimum number of blocks, so there is an on-going search for optimal designs, especially for $t > 2$.

For the "dual" packing problems (no two players meet more than once) with groups of five and six players, @EdPegg has posted [Social Golfer Problem - Quintets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69325/social-golfer-problem-quintets), asking what is known for certain universe sizes $v$.  No answers so far, but his Question does contain some informative links for smaller group sizes.