# Minimum number of sub groups so that each element is grouped with every other element at least once

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, permutations

Say we have a group containing 4 items $[A, B, C, D]$ and we allow sub-groups of size 2, then 6 sub-groups are needed to ensure every element is grouped with every other element at least once.

$[A,B] [A,C] [A,D] [B,C] [B,D] [C,D]$

or 3 if we allow sub-groups size 3

$[A,B,C] [A,B,D] [B,C,D]$

Expanding this to 8 elements and sub-groups size 4, 6 sub-groups are also required.

It also appears that if you have $n$ elements and a sub-group size $m$ which require $x$ sub-groups to ensure element grouping, then $kn$ elements with sub-group size $km$ also requires $x$ sub-groups. So possibly only prime numbers for $n$ or $m$ have unique values of $x$.

I tried initially looking at binary representations as a way to get all possible arrangements, then counting the instances of Hamming Weight $m$ from $0$ to $2^n$ but the pattern did not hold.

I am trying to generalize it so if you have $n$ elements with sub-group size $m$

$\binom{n}{m}$ where $1<m<n$ , $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ , $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

some function $F(n,m) = x$

Is  there a formular to express the minimum number of sub-groups size $m$ so that each element in $n$ is grouped with every other element at least once?

I'm having trouble describing elements as having already been grouped mathematically.

Comment: *social golfer problem*

Comment: Interesting. Although that refers to each player only playing once with every other player. My question is slightly less constrained that that.

Comment: Great resource for playing with this - https://goodenoughgolfers.com/

Comment: As you say @MikeS159 social golfer problem isn't quite the same. To put it succinctly, changing "at least" to "at most" in your question would give the social golfer problem. Changing it to "exactly" would give Kirkman's Schoolgirl Problem...sort of - there doesn't seem to be a commonly-accepted generalisation of that problem, but I'd content that'd be the most natural one.

Comment: Also, the standard terminology to use here would be 'set' not 'group' (the latter has a different, specific meaning in Algebra), and using curly braces `{ }` rather than square brackets `[ ]` to denote a set 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the smallest set of groups of $n$ elements such that every element is in the same group as every other at least once?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870422/how-can-i-find-the-smallest-set-of-groups-of-n-elements-such-that-every-elemen)