# Do you have to use Latin Squares to solve the Social Golfer's problem?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I'm trying to write a program to solve the social golfers program constrained to a certain number of weeks and so far I've been using the Latin Squares method detailed here: http://mathpages.com/home/kmath388.htm

[image]

Is there a better way to do it or is this the only algorithm?

Comment: See an earlier m.se post on social golfing, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69325/social-golfer-problem-quintets