# Rotating groups of people

Tags: combinatorics

I have a total of 30 people and I want to create rotating groups of 5 individuals. I have to come up with a system that allows each person to meet each other only once (maximum). As I already mentioned the meetings need to be in groups of 5. I have spent hours on it and got up to 3 parallel meetings.I just can't come up with the right algorithm to get this organised for 4 (or more if possible) parallel meetings. If it's not possible with a total of 30, please let me know a few different combinations (ex. number of meetings, total number of people, number of groups).

Very grateful for your assistance.

Comment: This is a variant on what is sometimes called "the social golfer problem". You will find a lot of stuff on the web, and previous questions on this website, if you search for that term.

Comment: For example, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69325/social-golfer-problem-quintets

Comment: While the Question seems very natural and "plain" to you, these problems may not have solutions.  One necessary condition is obvious to you, that the number of people in each grouping (*block* is the combinatorial term) must divide the total (here five divides thirty, so we are okay on that requirement).  But there are other conditions.   Suggested search terms:  resolvable block design.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: If you find anything out, Alexandros, please come back here to post an answer.

Comment: http://cs.brown.edu/~pvh/social.pdf

Comment: I think I linked to that paper in one of the older threads on the social golfer problem. Does something in that paper answer the "30 people in groups of 5" question?

Comment: I say, DOES SOMETHING IN THAT PAPER ANSWER THE "30 PEOPLE IN GROUPS OF 5" QUESTION?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.