# Partition a set into g groups, k different ways, such that no pair of elements is ever in the same group together more than M times

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, combinatorial-designs

Over at [Wolves and Sheep](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/81894/3896) on puzzling.stackexchange.com, noedne's answer involves repeatedly partitioning a group of 99 sheep into a series of "test groups" such that

> 1. All but one sheep are tested six times.
> 2. No pair of sheep shares more than one test.

This feels like it ought to be a well-studied combinatorics problem, something like a generalization of [Kirkman's schoolgirl problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman's_schoolgirl_problem), but I can barely *state* the generalized problem, let alone figure out how to Google it!

The problem is:

> Define a "partition of a set $S$ into $g$ groups" as a mapping $P : S \rightarrow [1..g]$.
>  
>   Given a collection $S$ of $n$ elements, produce $k$ different $g$-group partitions of the collection, such that no pair of elements is ever in the same group together more than $M$ times.
>   That is, produce $k$ different partitions $P_0, P_1, \cdots, P_k$ such that $\forall s_1, s_2\in S, \sum_{i\in [1..k]}{\big(P_i(s_1)=P_i(s_2)\big)} \leq M$.

noedne's answer to [Wolves and Sheep](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/81894/3896) gives one viable solution for $n=99$, $g=11$, $k=6$, $M=1$: "Given a collection $S$ of 99 elements, produce 6 different 11-group partitions of the collection, such that no pair of elements is ever in the same group together more than once."

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

So I'm asking you, Math StackExchange: What is the name of this problem, and what is known about the space of parameters $(n,k,g,M)$ for which it is solvable?

Comment: Hmm, following the "related questions" links, I suspect that for $M=1$ (which is the most interesting case anyway), this is exactly the "Social Golfers Problem"; see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69325/social-golfer-problem-quintets  I'm not sure what happens when we let $M$ vary, though!

Comment: This sounds similar to block design: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design

Comment: Yes this is just block designs

Comment: @Elaqqad: Uh-oh! [Fisher's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_inequality) states that if you tackle this problem using BIBDs, you will never ever find a solution where the total number of groups $b$ (which I called $k\cdot g$ above) is less than the number of elements $v$ (which I called $n = \lvert S\rvert$ above). So noedne's colorful solution above is not a BIBD, and BIBDs can't help us improve on it.

Comment: When you tackle the problem using BIBDs, you don't work with normal blocks, instead, you work with the the *dual" of the BIBDs, in the dual the points are the lines and the blocks are the points.

Comment: In the bock I mentioned in my answer (Combinatorial Designs: Constructions and Analysis), you can find this in section 11.3 Group Testing Algorithms (page 265). But using BIDDS, of course, constrains us in fact if you have, say $(v,k,1)$-BIBD then the relation is $b=(v^2-v)/(k^2-k)$ in your case $k=6$ (a BIBD induces a solution with $k-1$ defectives ) . the $b$ is the number of points so it is equal to $100$. this implies that $v\geq 46$

Comment: If don't think that BIBD is the way forward to get a better solution, Because it' is an open problem if there is a BIBD $(61,6,1)$ (or at least a difference set) which if it does exist it gives you a new bound (but we don't think that it does exist). If there is a new bound it should be based on something else, like PDBs, free cover families, d-disjunct matrices, generalized quadrangles ..... .There are a lot of methods to tackle the group testing problem. Your question is what do we call this model and what is known about it and that's only what my answer discusses.

Comment: @Elaqqad: I don't understand what you mean at all, then. Could you post an example of a block design that solves _any_ instance of the Wolves and Sheep problem — say, for 2 wolves out of 8 sheep? My impression from your initial answer had been that to find 2 wolves out of 8 sheep you'd have to find a BIBD for $(v\ge 8, b=\textrm{minimal}, r=3, k=?, \lambda=1)$. Your latest comment says nope, you'd have to find a BIBD for $(v=\textrm{minimal}, b\ge 8, r=?, k=3, \lambda=1)$. But I still don't see either how to find that BIBD nor how it would be massaged back into a Wolves and Sheep solution.

Comment: if you read carefully, the second generalization on my answer you will find out that my comment coincides with it, for the example you gave the second interpretation $(v=\textrm{minimal}, b\ge 8, r=?, k=3, \lambda=1)$ is the correct one.

Comment: Also, in the end of my answer, there are two examples (not developed completely, I will try to add more details later on ,this is my phone, and I can't really write it now)  If the subject is new to you, then you have to follow alongside the book and do some exercises and examples in order to understand.  I have another very good book on the subject (more recent) https://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Combinatorial-Discrete-Mathematics-Applications/dp/1584885068 (I can send to you by email if you want it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is [block designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design), precisely $BIBD$s. This answer can be viewed as a comment. In the first part, it states the main question and its relation to group testing and design theory. In the second part, it tries to analyze the given solution to the puzzle and gives one generalization. And in the third part, it states the definition of balanced incomplete block designs and references a book containing a comprehensive analysis.

---

First of all, let's state the original puzzle:

**Question:** 
Given a large population of *items* (sheep) containing a small set of *defectives* (Wolves), Assuming you can perform a test on a group of items and get a positive result if and only if the group contains a defective. How many tests are required to identify all the defectives?

> **Mathematically**, given integers $d<n$, and $X$ a set of size $n$, we call a family $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of $X$ $d$*-distinguishing*, if the function $f : {n \choose X} \to 2^ \mathcal{F}$ defined by $A \mapsto \{X\in \mathcal{F}, X\cap A \neq \varnothing \}$ is injective. What is the minimum size of a $d$*-distinguishing* family $\mathcal{F}$ denoted by  $t(n,d)=|\mathcal{F}|$ ?

In [Combinatorial design theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_design), one of the most beautiful areas of mathematics, this is called the [Group Testing Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_testing). It is a very well studied subject because it has a lot of applications. It's very difficult to navigate all the research done on it but for the interested, I can refer to the survey [Combinatorial Group Testing and Its Applications.](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/4252) by D. Du and F. Hwang.

To summarise, the only value for which $t(n,d)$ is known completely is $d=1$ for which $t(n,1)=\lceil \log n\rceil$, the exact value even for $d=2$ is not known. Generally, the solutions to this problem are called *testing designs*, and the main considered ones are:

1. Set-packing designs or [block designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design).
2. [Transversal designs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TransversalDesign.html).
3. Designs whose [$d$-disjunct or $d$-separable matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunct_matrix) are directly constructed.

Using these methods, It's known that :
$$\frac{d^2}{2\log(d)}\log(n) \leq t(n,d) \leq d^2 \log e(1+o(1)) \log(n) $$

This basically suggests that for your puzzle, the solution would be close to $30$.

---

Now returning to the answer given for the puzzle. Basically, the design that is proposed is the following :

**Solution:** First of all, put all the items in a grid $11\times 11$ and then create a set of tests, each test corresponds to a line in that grid. Additionally, every line contains every item exactly $6$ times and every two lines intersect in only one point. then every $5$ items (points) subset is a member of a nonshared set of lines.

> **Mathematically**, Given a field $\Bbb F$, and $X \subset \Bbb F^2$ a subset of pairs of size $n$.  For any $A \subset \Bbb F$ define the following family 
>   $$\mathcal{L}_{A}=\Big\{L(a,b)=\{x+ay=b, (x,y)\in X\}, a\in A , b\in \Bbb F \Big\} $$
>   then $\mathcal{L}_{A}$ is $d$*-distinguishing* for $X$ of size $|A||\Bbb F|$ for any $d<|A|$.

*Proof*: This formalizes the set of lines in a $2$ dimensional space over $\Bbb F$. Because of the fact that all the matrices $\begin{pmatrix}1&a\\1&a'\end{pmatrix}, a\neq a'\in A$ are invertible (thus fixes $b$), each two lines intersect only in one point. and of course, the definition ensures that every item is a member of exactly |A| groups.

*Remarks*:

- In the puzzle $|X| = 100$, $|\Bbb F|=11$, $|A|=6$ and $d=5$.
- The design applies to up to $|X|=121$ without changing the number of tests
- This implies that $t(n,d) \leq (d+1)p^k \sim (d+1)\sqrt n$ where $p^k$ is the smallest prime power $\geq \sqrt n$
- Of course this is not the optimal solution.

One first generalization of this solution is to consider higher dimensions, but a very difficult constraint arizes, mainly that of [No-three-in-line problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-three-in-line_problem) and more (this is because of the argument of matrix invertible above).

> **First generalization (dimension $=3$)**, Given a field $\Bbb F$, and $X \subset \Bbb F^3$.  For any $A \subset \Bbb F^2$ with no three colinear points, define the following family 
>   $$\mathcal{L}_{A}=\Big\{L(a,b,c)=\{x+ay+bz=c, (x,y,z)\in X\}, (a,b)\in A , c\in \Bbb F \Big\} $$
>   then $\mathcal{L}_{A}$ is $d$*-distinguishing* for $X$ of size $|A||\Bbb F|$ for any $d$ such that $2d<|A|$.

*Proof*: This is the set of planes in a $3$ dimensional space over $\Bbb F$. Because of the fact that all the matrices $\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\1&a'&b'\\1&a''&b''\end{pmatrix}$ are invertible for distinct $(a,b),(a',b'),(a'',b'')\in A$, each three planes intersect only in one point. and of course, the definition ensures that every item is a member of exactly |A| groups. The proof is the same as before, in fact, it is just an application of the generalized pigeonhole principle. This is why we need the last inequality $2d<|A|$.

*Remarks*:

- The non-$3$-colinearity condition is very strong, and the existence of such points requires $|A| \leq \sqrt {|F|} $, which in our cases is not applicable.
- This implies for $n>> d^6$ that $t(n,d) \leq (2d+1)p^k \sim (2d+1)\sqrt[3] n$ where $p^k$ is the smallest prime power $\geq \sqrt[3] n$
- Of course this remains not the optimal solution.

This two types of solutions are called grid designs (or affine planes, projective planes in combinatorial design theory) and they are also studied by for example Hwang in the book I [referenced above](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/4252). In their constructions, the property that no two points are in the same line twice is called the unique collinearity condition.

---

These methods - when not randomized - don't give us better bounds. The main methods used in the field are block designs and direct constructions of the matrices. Your generalization is equivalent to the following

> **Second generalization**. Let $n$, $g$, and $M$ be positive integers such that $n > g \geq 2$. A $(n, g, M)$-*balanced incomplete block design* (which we abbreviate to $(n, g, M)$-BIBD) is a design $(X, \mathcal A)$ such that the following properties are satisfied:
>
> 1. $|X| = n$,
> 2. each block contains exactly $g$ points, and
> 3. every pair of distinct points is contained in exactly $M$ blocks.
>
> then the dual of every $(t, g, 1)$-BIBD is $(g-1)$-*distinguishing* of size $t$ for a set $Y$ of size $\frac{t^2-t}{k^2-k}$.

The third property above is called the balance property, which you do not require in your definition. If it's relaxed to "every pair of distinct points is contained in no more then $M$ blocks", the design will be called an *incomplete block design*. Also, we can relax the second property by allowing multiple block sizes in a set of integers $G$. We obtain a $\bf{(t,G,M)}$**-pairwise block design**. This is exactly what you are looking for.

All the results I know are focused on $BIBD$s (and $PDB$s, ...) as combinatorial structures. This is a very largely studied subject and in any book on Design Theory (for example *[Combinatorial Designs: Constructions and Analysis](http://mathscinet.ru/files/StinsonD.pdf)*) you will find a lot of examples, constructions, and conditions of existence.

The book contains an example of $(37, 4, 1)$-BIBD (resp. $(19, 3, 1)$-BIBD) which means that we can identify $3$ (resp. $2$) defective items in a group of size $\frac{37^2-37}{4^2-4}=111$ (resp. $58$) using $37$ (resp. $19$) tests. These specific block designs generally provide a solution with an order of magnitude $t(d,n) \sim d\sqrt n$.

---

***Edit :*** As you requested here is an example of how you can solve a group testing problem given a block design. An example of $(37,4,1)$-BIBD can be constructed as follows, Let $D_1=\{0,1,3,24\}$, $D_2=\{0,10,18,30\}$ and $D_3=\{0,4,26,32\}$ (a difference family), now define : 
$$
    X=\Bbb{Z}_{37}=\{0,....,36\} \\
    B_{i,j}=\{ d+j , d \in D_i\}, i\in {1,2,3}, j\in X
$$

Addition is done modulo $37$, the number of blocks is $111$, size of $X$ is $37$ and each block contains exactly $4$ elements of $X$.

Now given $111$ items (Sheep), assign every sheep to a block in the example, and create the following tests $T_x=\{B\in \mathcal{B}, x \in B\}$ for each $x\in \Bbb{Z}_{37}$. I claim that these $37$ tests are sufficient to find $4-1=3$ defective items (wolves) in the original set.

In your puzzle, what you need is $(v,6,1)$-BIBD with $v\geq 46$ (or a $(v,\Bbb{N}_{\geq 6},1)$-PBD) if you have done some research on this you will find that :

1. If there is a $(v,6,1)$-BIBD, then $v \equiv 1,3 \mod 15$.
2. It is proven that there is no $(46,6,1)$-BIBD
3. It is an open problem if there is $(v,6,1)$-BIBD for a finite list$v=51, 61, ...$ (as far as I know)
   Using BIBDs the best solution we can get less than $63$ is $61$ but that's an open problem.

What I have tried (without success) is to find instead $(v,\{6,7,8\},1)$-PBD ($v$ should be bigger than $42$).

**Edit:** Using packings, which is the structure that satisfies your two conditions (kind of), then if a solution exists for your puzzle that satisfies both conditions, it should contain at least $56$ tests. The argument is based on the fact that every packing design satisfies $D(v,k,2) \leq  \left\lfloor \frac v k \lfloor \frac {v-1}{k-1}\rfloor \right\rfloor$.

**Solution for your puzzle** A possible answer for your puzzle with $60$ tests. 
First, consider the following $4$ base blocks :

```
BaseBlocks = [
    {(0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,2),(0,2,1,0),(1,0,1,1), (1,1,1,2), (1,2,∞,∞)},
    {(0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,1),(1,0,0,2),(1,1,0,2), (1,2,1,1), (0,2,∞,∞)},
    {(0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,2,1,1),(1,0,0,0), (1,1,0,3), (1,2,∞,-∞)},
    {(0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,3),(1,0,1,3),(1,1,1,1), (1,2,0,3), (0,2,∞,-∞)}
]
```

Now consider the following blocks (addition is done modulo the subscripts, and infinity plus anything stays the same) :

```
Blocks = [ 
   { (a,b+i,c+j,d+k) , (a,b,c,d) in B}
   B in BaseBlocks
   i in Z_3
   j in Z_2
   k in Z_4
]
```

There are exactly $96$ blocks. There are $60$ points of the form $(a,b,c,d)$ in the union of those blocks. Now as for the first example, the blocks correspond to Sheep and the points to the tests. Up to here, with these $60$ tests, you can find $5$ wolves among $96$ sheep.

But actually you can add $8$ more sheep, By adding more blocks :

```
Blocks' = Blocks ∪ [ 
   {(0,0,∞, ∞),(0,1,∞, ∞),(0,2,∞, ∞),(1,0,∞,-∞),(1,1,∞,-∞),(1,2,∞,-∞)},
   {(0,0,∞,-∞),(0,1,∞,-∞),(0,2,∞,-∞),(1,0,∞, ∞),(1,1,∞, ∞),(1,2,∞, ∞)},

   // The pattern : all the first two elements are the same
   {(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1),(0,0,0,2),(0,0,0,3),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,1,1),(0,0,1,2),(0,0,1,3)},
   {(0,1,0,0),(0,1,0,1),(0,1,0,2),(0,1,0,3),(0,1,1,0),(0,1,1,1),(0,1,1,2),(0,1,1,3)},
   {(0,2,0,0),(0,2,0,1),(0,2,0,2),(0,2,0,3),(0,2,1,0),(0,2,1,1),(0,2,1,2),(0,2,1,3)},
   {(1,0,0,0),(1,0,0,1),(1,0,0,2),(1,0,0,3),(1,0,1,0),(1,0,1,1),(1,0,1,2),(1,0,1,3)},
   {(1,1,0,0),(1,1,0,1),(1,1,0,2),(1,1,0,3),(1,1,1,0),(1,1,1,1),(1,1,1,2),(1,1,1,3)},
   {(1,2,0,0),(1,2,0,1),(1,2,0,2),(1,2,0,3),(1,2,1,0),(1,2,1,1),(1,2,1,2),(1,2,1,3)}
]
```

Now with this, you can find $5$ wolves among $104$ sheep using $60$ tests !

Comment: "Of course this is not the optimal solution" — why "of course"? Do you know of a better solution, or do you mean more like "Of course _the odds are that_ this is not the optimal solution"?  Related: when you say that "for your puzzle, the solution would be close to 30," do you have any sense of the error-bars on that? When I plug d=5, n=100 into your formulas, I get "35.7 ≤ t(100, 5) ≤ 115+epsilon", which seems very different from "close to 30."

Comment: "being close to $30$" is just my intuition not a fact, however, it is based on the fact that all the solutions we know (even consider) are based on some specific type of structure that we understand well, and therefore we restrict ourselves in a very small subset. The actual search space is much much larger than what is taken into account in those specific mechanisms.  The asymptotics there are only when $n$ is very large ( I don't know how much exactly) and we can't apply them for small values (I forgot something in the formula). The only bound we have for sure is $t(5,100)\geq 27$.

Comment: But certainly is not the optimal solution, as there are other more complicated mechanisms that give us better bounds.  I actually have a solution with 47, but the details are very messy and it could require writing a lot, I am not sure if I should include it in the answer without those messy details.

Comment: In fact, all the solutions that came for a  $BIBD$ can give only a number of tests $t$  that satisfy $t^2-t\geq 2000$ which means, that the best we can hope for using BIBD is a solution with $46$ tests. If we need a better solution we have to consider some new (probably more complicated) type of block designs

Comment: If you have a solution to ["Wolves and Sheep"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81737/wolves-and-sheep/) in 47 (or any-fewer-than-63) tests, then you should post it over there! You don't even have to explain it at all, let alone the "messy details," if you don't want to.  It's quick and easy for anyone to verify that a solution is a solution; for example I have a C++ program to verify proposed solutions [here](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/wolves-and-sheep/blob/master/main_verifysolution.cc).

Comment: I will try to do that hen I have some time (need to create the matrix).

Comment: I just tried to apply your "First generalization" to t(n=100,d=5). Unfortunately, it seems to say that we should start with an _A_ of size 11 or more, which makes for more than 121 tests if I understand your notation correctly. So not only it "remains not the optimal solution," but it becomes much worse than the [worst possible solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/81871/3896)? ;p Seems like these generalizations have good asymptotics but really poor constant factors, and thus aren't likely to help with "small" concrete examples like t(100,5). Yes/no?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's what I meant by "which in our cases is not applicable". I discovered an error in my solution with 47 tests. Maybe 30 is completely off the scale.  Small cases are really hard it seems.

Comment: @Quuxplusone I added some more explanations, and also I explained how you can find $3$ wolves in a pack of $111$ sheep using $37$ tests (can you verify that it works using a computer ? mathematically it should)

Comment: Note that if you follow the same approach as noedne's answer, then you will get originally 44 tests ( instead of 66), but as he did, we can probably reduce that number by removing some tests.  Also if you reduce the number of sheep to $105$ then we can do it in $36$ tests using a $(36,4,1)-BIBD$.

Comment: "find 3 wolves in a pack of 111 sheep using 37 tests (can you verify that it works using a computer?" — Yes, verified! Thank you very much! I have added that solution to my GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/wolves-and-sheep/commit/5f0cc0586f5e96a3353abd03848db317e59c34cd).

Comment: @Quuxplusone, I added a solution for your puzzle with $60$ tests. Can you please test it ?

Comment: Your t(96,5)=60 solution works fine! Your t(102,5)=60 solution fails, assuming I have transcribed it correctly: https://github.com/Quuxplusone/wolves-and-sheep/commit/11583400 produces indistinguishable wolf-arrangements https://pastebin.com/TQZDUap6 . I'll investigate more later.

Comment: Yeah, you're right I made a mistake, I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that. The updated answer should be the correct one.

Comment: Also, this should work even if you don't know initially how many wolves are there but you know that there are no more than $5$. Because all the combinations with less than $5$ elements produce different outputs. That's why I would say this is not optimal we can just deduce that $t(104,5)\leq 60$ ( we can probably remove some tests for the case $t(100,5) $)

Comment: Your t(104,5)=60 solution works! https://pastebin.com/b9w90YTH FYI, I *had* misinterpreted your earlier t(102,5)=60 solution — I had added the new blocks to the list of *base blocks*, instead of to the final generated list of blocks. But I didn't go back and re-test after realizing that, because you'd already updated your solution into t(104,5)=60. If you remove the first test, t(100,5)=59 also works. https://github.com/Quuxplusone/wolves-and-sheep/commit/b2f29faa

Comment: Great!, you can post that on the other site if you want. I don't have enough points to do so.

Comment: You don't have enough points to post an _answer_? That's not possible AFAIK (unless you just don't have an account over there at all, and really don't want to create one). I'll give you another day-ish to reconsider, ;) and then I'll happily post your answer with credit and as much explanation as I can reliably reproduce, and take all the upvotes for myself. ;)

Comment: Yes, because the question is Highly active. You have done work too, you deserve the upvotes!

Comment: Posted! https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/92546/3896