# How can I construct a $(v,\Bbb{N}_{\geq 6},1)$ pairwise balanced design?

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

I have recently answered *[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3195281/partition-a-set-into-g-groups-k-different-ways-such-that-no-pair-of-elements-i/3488985#3488985)*, in which I described how solving a puzzle in group testing is related to constructing a block design. But I did not succeed in providing a better answer to the puzzle. In my approach, I tried to create a $(v,\Bbb{N}_{\geq 6},1)$ pairwise balanced design with $v$ minimal and with more than $100$ blocks. So here is my question :

> How can I construct a $\mathbf{(v,K,1)}$ **[pairwise balanced design](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Pairwise_balanced_design)** with minimal $v$, with more than $100$ blocks and $K\subset \Bbb{N}_{\geq 6}$?

$\Bbb{N}_{\geq 6}$ denotes the set of integers larger than or equal to $6$, in my search I tried for $v\in [46,60],K={6,7,8}$.

Also, I wonder if there is some software that can generate PBDs and other combinatorial designs?

---

**Definition** : Given $v \geq 2$ and $K\subset \Bbb N$, a $(v, K,1)$-pairwise balanced design (for short $(v, K,1)$-PBD) is a pair $(V,\mathcal B)$ of a finite set of points of cardinality $|V|=v$ and a family of subsets (blocks) of $V$ which satisfy the properties:

1. If $B\in \mathcal {B}$ then $|B|\in K$
2. Every pair of distinct elements of $V$ occurs in exactly in one block.

Comment: If $K=\mathbb{N}_{\geq 6}$, your blocks have at least 6 elements and thus $15$ distincts pairs in each of them. Since every distinct pair of elements of $V$ occurs only once, with 100 blocks you need to have $V$ large enough to have $1500$ distincts pairs, then $v\geq 55$. For the generation, what if you draw your blocks randomly and reject them if they contain an already existing pair ?

Comment: Yes I think we do have that $v\geq 55$, I did not try to do it randomly, I should try that